# File descriptors, terminal, and open file description

Tags: c, shell, terminal, stream, zsh

Consider this simple program:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main () {
  write(STDIN_FILENO, "hello\n", 6);
  return 0;
}
```

and that the output will be viewed on the terminal even if I replace `STDIN_FILENO` with `STDERR_FILENO` xor `STDOUT_FILENO`.

I understand that `bash` holds fd `255`, (`zsh`, `10`), for special purpose to maintain access to the terminal when one file descriptor is closed. This seems to imply that there is no real difference in the underlying representation for the associated streams.

My question is as follows:

- what distinguishes the "stream devices" STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR?
- Do they share the same open file description, so that a write to one advances the `lseek()` offset of another? How would a program such as:

```
$ cat
hello
hello
```

work otherwise without them overwriting eachother?

On my Linux VM (using `zsh`), it can be seen:

```
$ ls -l /proc/$$/fd
total 0
lrwx------ ... ... ... 0 -> /dev/tty1
lrwx------ ... ... ... 1 -> /dev/tty1
lrwx------ ... ... ... 10 -> /dev/tty1
lrwx------ ... ... ... 2 -> /dev/tty1
```

so it seems that they do share the same device, and I was hoping for more insight on this.

Comment: They are three separate file descriptors. `0`, `1` and `2` in normal cases.

Comment: Well of course ... but that wasn't what I was asking. I'm asking about the underlying open file description, what this means for the "file offset" --> I had thought streams do not have a notion of one, and how it interacts with the terminal -> since it seems that `STDIN_FILENO` has write capability.

Comment: I'm not sure that character devices have an `lseek()` offset. Writing into one won't appear in its input. It's not a loopback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between stdin and STDIN\_FILENO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102992/what-is-the-difference-between-stdin-and-stdin-fileno)

Comment: POSIX requires that `STDIN_FILENO` equals to 0. This certainly is the case if you run under Linux. Similarily, stdout has on Posix systems the value 1 and stderr has 2.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507057/what-are-the-possible-values-for-file-descriptors) for other FD values. Note also that these filedesciptors (0-2) are not seekable. If this doesn't answer your question, I don't really understand what you are asking.

Comment: What I was asking, which apparently I did not make clear, is the internal representation of the fds 0, 1, 2 and how it seems they share an open file description, and perhaps more insight into what the terminal is actually doing, since it seems you can write to `STDIN_FILENO` with the same results as writing to `STDOUT_FILENO`.

Comment: A file descriptor is just a non-negative integer number. As such, it has no internat representation. In terms of implementation, a file descriptor is typically an index into an array of elements, each of them describing a file. I guess that the internals of such an array depend at least on the operating system, maybe also on the programming lanuage you are using.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) how these structures typically look like. Why do you want to fiddle with these internals? Are you going to write a compiler, or a new operating system?

Comment: BTW, if you are in particular interested in descriptors which work like stdin or stdout, you can find [here](https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/labs/device_drivers.html) the implementation details for Linux.