# Error Encountered while Dynamic Memory allocation in C

Tags: c, pointers

In the below code, `line[]` array contains names of all image files contained in a folder. We are just reading the names dynamically and sending the file names one by one to a function `function_foo` as given in the code. When there are 8 images the code is executing as expected. But as soon as we increase the number of image files in the folder to any number above 8, the process gets terminated and returns -1. Please suggest.

```
FILE **fp;
struct Structure_Name data[100];
fp = malloc( sizeof(FILE *) * 10000);

for(i=0;i<total; i++)
{
  sprintf(fName,"/home/souvik/Images/%s",line[i]);
  printf("%s\n",fName);
  fp[i] = fopen(fName, "rb");
  data[i]=function_foo(fp[i],(data[i]));
}
```

Comment: show us the complete code (mini-version in case of large code), and more importantly, what have you tried? (something like google about gdb, valgrind )

Comment: just reading multiple image file from a folder using gcc linux. The function_foo returns the rows and column data of an image. Structure_Name is a structure for holding the image data.

Comment: Is there are reason why you aren't using an array? `FILE* fp_arr = malloc( sizeof(FILE*[n]) );`

Comment: What is the value of 'total' etc.?   Not what you think it is, what it actually is - from your debugger.:)

Comment: What is line[] and what is it filled with?

Comment: You are not giving us enough - read again what @abasu wrote above.

Comment: Hi James, total = number of files in a directory; line[ ] contains the names of the files that are there in the directory.

Comment: yes the file names are correct and NULL check has also been done, see the Update given by iila below..

Answer (score 2):

It is a really bad idea to open 10000 files at the same time. I'd recommend you to change this logic: to read content of these files one by one, and to send this content to your function `function_foo`. But currently your code tries to `fopen` very big number of files without closing of it. I expect it is the main problem (i.e. it seems that in your environment maximal number of files that can by opened is 8).

See also:

- [Maximum number of files that can be opened by c "fopen" in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931583/maximum-number-of-files-that-can-be-opened-by-c-fopen-in-linux)
- [Is there a limit on number of open files in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870173/is-there-a-limit-on-number-of-open-files-in-windows)

**Update:**

Since you don't need an array of all pointers, you can try following version. Do you see the same problem in this case?

```
FILE *fp;
struct Structure_Name data[100];

for(i=0; i<total; i++)
{
  sprintf(fName,"/home/souvik/Images/%s", line[i]);
  printf("%d of %d, %s\n", i, total, fName);
  fp = fopen(fName, "rb");
  if (fp != NULL)
  {
    data[i]=function_foo(fp,(data[i]));
    fclose(fp);
  } else
  {
    printf("A null pointer is returned by fopen()");
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I have included fclose(fp[i]) , after calling the function function_foo inside the loop. That means now the files are closed after reading is done. But the same problem persists. Again, by reducing the value 10000 to 10 the program is able to open only 2 files. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer (and added an information about `total`, requested by Martin James). Please tell us, do you see the same problem.

Comment: The same error : 
total=11
0 of 11, /home/souvik/Images/LPF_ChangeR_-4.pgm
1 of 11, /home/souvik/Images/LPF_ChangeR_3.pgm
2 of 11, /home/souvik/Images/LPF_ChangeR_-5.pgm
3 of 11, /home/souvik/Images/LPF_ChangeR_5.pgm
4 of 11, /home/souvik/Images/LPF_ChangeR_-3.pgm
5 of 11, /home/souvik/Images/LPF_ChangeR_1.pgm
6 of 11, /home/souvik/Images/LPF_ChangeR_4.pgm
7 of 11, /home/souvik/Images/LPF_ChangeR_-1.pgm
8 of 11, /home/souvik/Images/LPF_ChangeR_0.pgm
9 of 11, /home/souvik/Images/LPF_ChangeR_2.pgm

Process returned -1 (0xFFFFFFFF)   execution time : 42.209 s
Press ENTER to continue.

Comment: I'll suggest use valgrind and check, if it is running for 42.209 s, there's some heavyweight things being done, have you tried some simple things like, instead of function_foo, do a fseek and print the size, see, if you are getting the data or not, try to triangulate the problem

Comment: all the data upto data[9] are obtained and the the program returns -1 while fetching the 10th file name (i.e. when i = 10 in the loop ). Any suggestion ?

Comment: @SouvikKundu in your code the array `data` contains only 100 elements, but the array `fp` contains 10000 elements. And after it you call `function_foo(fp[i],(data[i]))` (i.e. with the same index `i`). I expect that you have similar mistakes somewhere else in this program (and it might be the reason of breaking of something unexpected in the memory).

Answer (score 0):

@ALL, Thanks for your active help.

Now the problem is solved. The root cause of the problem was that, while the program was looping through all the images it was storing the image data in data[i] , i.e. data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4]......... the data is temporarily stored in \var folder during program execution. after reading 9 image files the total size of 9 images (data[1]+data[2]+data[3]+..... data[9]) exceeds the size of \var in our machines. We simply de-allocated the space allocated for the structure variable data[i] after each iteration. This solved the problem.